# Algorithm / Function to find weighting of parameters how influens on result

Tags: excel, database, algorithm, matlab, statistics

Im trying to find a way to predict high Results based on statistics data, thats why I need to find weights of parameters.

I have a data sample with following structure:

| Price A | Price B | Price C | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 9 | 80 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 30 |

On that structure I would like to calculate weights for
Price A , Price B, Price C **to predict highest values of result column**

Basing on my previous structure Price C seems to be most valued weight,
so weight for Price C should be the highest one.

So for data:

[image]

weightA * priceA + weightB * priceB + weightC * priceC = should generate Result value something around 80, but for second row there should be ~30 predicted

I've tried something with Pearson algorithm (in excel) but I didn't get 'good' results :(.

Comment: but I d.... what?

Comment: Updated bro....

Comment: Define "good" what the trends may imply or what you want?

Comment: Because pearson is for: how parameter a influens on parameter c.
If parameter a it influens in 80% on parameter c
and parameter b influens in 10% on parameter c
how I can find weight for parameter a ?